# Deploying IPA on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, itunes

I'm trying to deploy my ipa to my iphone. but the blue outlines don't seem to appear on itunes. I've deployed a app to this device before but it seems after i updated my iPhone it isn't possible anymore. iTunes is updated to the latest update, which is 11.2.1 atm.

Using a mac in our network to build from, development is being done on a PC.

[image]

I have an apple developer account, the UDID is added to the iOS Provisioning Profile.

In the app the bundle identifie is set to the App ID in the provisioning profile.

What i've tried is to untrust all pc's doing (both):

> To untrust all computers, tap *Settings > General > Reset > Reset*
>   *Location & Privacy*. This will also reset your location and privacy
>   settings. You can also untrust all computers by tapping *Settings >*
>   *General > Reset > Reset Network Settings*. This will also reset your
>   network settings.

Rebuild the application from scratch and still no luck, even with nothing in the project but the `mainpage.xaml` ( welcome to xamarin forms message ). app is build in xamarin

Add a colleague his iphone to profile, and rebuilding it. That works and i get to deploy the ipa to **his** iphone. I tried switching phones again, no luck there. He's updated to the latest ios version as wel.

So basicly my iphone won't accept my build.

Comment: Did you uninstall the old app first and then deploy?

Comment: ofcourse i have :)

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the another way to test your IPA in your device**

If you have added UDID in your provisioning profile then,

Upload your IPA on `https://www.diawi.com/` after uploading it will generate sharable link. Open this link in your device with safari browser and allow to download the application. This will download the application in your device and test your application.

Comment: i really dislike the fact that i have to use a work around for something that has worked before...

Answer (score 0):

you can install through xcode. In xcode go window->Devices and simulators.Select Phone . Click on + button select IPA.It will install ipa in phone.

Comment: edited the main post, using a mac that's in our network. Development is being done on a PC